# MODX Revo - Unable to upload or view files in File section in Manager

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I'm having problems uploading and even viewing files in the File section of MODX Revolution 2.2.3-pl. When I try to upload a file, all I get is "Upload error". Nothing shows up in the Filesystem area, just a folder called Media that doesn't let me do anything. Any ideas of what might be going on?

As far as file system permissions go, all folders are set to 755 and all files are set to 644. I'm seeing this behavior logged in as admin/sudo. I just moved my installation of MODX from my local machine, where I believe it worked right, to a shared hosting environment, and that's where I'm seeing this issue.

Comment: same here, have you managed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a recent [update to 2.2.4-pl](http://modx.com/download/distribution/revolution-2.2.4-pl-standard) after [reported problems](http://tracker.modx.com/issues/8110) with the file manager.

I'd recommend updating to 2.2.4-pl and check if the problem is still present.

Comment: Took me a bit to finally get around to installing the 2.2.4-pl update, but that fixed it. Thanks for making me aware of the update.

Answer (score 0):

Also it could be that your MOD system settings have `Use Multibyte Extension` enabled but PHP hasn’t been compiled with the –enable-mbstring option.

Hidden away in the MODx Media Browser is a failed response to a JSON request and an error message showing…

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtolower() in on line 168

If you can’t recompile PHP or just need to get your Media Browser working again, go to `System Settings` and set `Multibyte Extension` to `No`.

All the credit to [Max Mitchell's Post].[1](http://www.maxy.com/modx-media-browser-not-showing-any-files/)